# How to link external .js file in .php file

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to simply call a JavaScript function that is found an external file. My folder structure is:

C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php

C:\xampp\htdocs\test\js\functions.js

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("content.php"); ?>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f0aaae8537.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

  <script>
    test();
   </script>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
function test(){
   alert("where am i");
}
```

I am using VS Code and XAMPP. The function test is not being called. It works when I define the function inside index.php but not in the external file. I have tried including the attribute type="text/javascript" and moving the functions.js file to the root folder "test" but still nothing.

Comment: `<script src="/js/functions.js"></script>` does this not work?

Comment: Are you sure `test` (and not `htdocs`) is the root folder? What URL loads the HTML document? What URL does the developer tools Network tab say is being requested for the script?

Comment: It looks fine...are you getting errors?

Comment: What does the browser console show?.

Comment: try this please: `<script src="js/functions.js"></script>` no slash before `js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `js` is not in the root folder and therefore you `script` tag may need to be:

```
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

Note the absence of `/` before `js`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

In functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function test(){
     alert("where am i");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` otherwise it'll be treated as a path starting from `/` (the root directory of wherever the file is being run, most likely the web server.):

```
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
```